# Qt3D emissive materials possible? (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I was wondering whether it's possible to make some type of emissive material in Qt3D using C++. I've been checking the documentation for anything related to this in the different materials available in Qt, but have been unable to find anything with such a parameter.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!